# How do I limit a text file which is a leaderboard to five names and also order them in terms of points

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code for adding to the file

```
user = str(input("Congratulations. Enter your name Player 1 to save your highscore: "))
#Leaderboard
file = open("Leaderboard.txt", "a")
#adds user name
file.write(user)
file.write(", ")
file.write(str(score1))
#adds no of points
file.write("pts")
file.write(", ")
#adds date
file.write(today)
file.write("\n")
file.close()
import leaderboard
file = open("Leaderboard.txt","r") 
for line in file:
    print(line)  
file.close()
```

How can i limit the text file to five people and also order it every time a game is played so it outputs the leaderboard in order of their scores??

Comment: First, you need to implement reader of your file. Then, when you read all the players from the file, store them in a list. Furthermore, sort the list by points and write the first 5 items from the list to the file. Try this and come back with what you have done.

Comment: @NutCracker Ok I've stored them in a list and tried sorting it again. It works now, thank you.

Comment: I will post an answer so you can accept it and other can benefit from it. You may also update your question with the code that worked for you.

Comment: And if my answer helped you, please upvote or accept or both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you should follow to solve your problem so you can code it yourself and learn from it ;):

1. you need to implement reader of your file
2. when you read all the players from the file, store them in a list
3. sort the list by points
4. write the first 5 items from the list to the file

Simple enough :)